# Update firestore database via ArrayUnion

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I want to update my firestore database by creating an ArrayUnion Object. 
Unfortunately my update method produces the following error:

```
 TypeError: ('Cannot convert to a Firestore Value', <google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.transforms.ArrayUnion object at 0x04CDEF90>,
'Invalid type', <class 'google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.transforms.ArrayUnion'>)
```

My approach is based on the official docs https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/firestore/google/cloud/firestore_v1beta1/_helpers.py

This implementation worked for me in the past, but for a couple of days i cant get it to succeed.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore
from firebase_admin import db    
from google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1 import ArrayUnion, ArrayRemove

class TwitFire:

    def __init__(self):
       # Use a service account
       cred = credentials.Certificate('./credentials')
       firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
       self.client = firestore.client()

    def getRef(self, collectionName, documentName):
        return self.client.collection(collectionName).document(documentName)

    def set(self, ref, entry):
        return ref.set(entry)

    def update(self, ref, entry):
        return ref.update(entry)

    def updateTweets(self, ref, entry):
        return ref.update({u'retweets': ArrayUnion([entry])})

    def create(self, ref, entry):
        return ref.create(entry)
```

Comment: Just wanted to confirm that i was indeed using google-cloud-firestore==0.32.1

Comment: Apparently the right import should be `from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import ArrayUnion` [see](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7720)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `google-cloud-firestore==0.32.1`?

Experienced the same issue when I upgraded to `32.1`.

Downgraded to `google-cloud-firestore==0.31.0` and the issue is gone.
Maybe a bug in the recent version.

Note that I did not tested locally, just changed the `requirements.txt`

EDIT:

```
from google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1 import ArrayUnion
```

should be used with `0.31.0`
when using `0.32.0` and above the import must be:

```
from google.cloud.firestore_v1 import ArrayUnion
```

See [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/7720)